# Is the ideal, prime? maximal? Is it principal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

im sitting with this exercise:

> Let $J$ be the ideal of $\mathbb Q[x]$ generated by two polynomials: $f(x)=(x+1)(x+2)(x^2+1)$ and $g(x)=(x+1)^2(x+2)^2$. Is the ideal $J$ prime? Is it maximal? Is it principal?

I would like to know if my solution is correct:

So the gcd between f(x) and g(x) would be $\gcd(f(x),g(x))=(x+1)(x+2)$.

Therefore the principal ideal J will be generated by $(x+1)(x+2)=x^2+3x+2$.

Because this polynomial clearly is reducible the quotient ring cannot be a field or integral domain. And therefore it will not be a maximal or prime ideal.

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Seems correct to me. $J$ will be _the ideal generated by_  $x^2 + 3x + 2$.

Comment: $\mathbb Q[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, so $J$ will automatically be principal. You say "the ideal cannot be a field or integral domain." You probably mean the quotient by the ideal.

Comment: There is some incorrect usage of terms here, which either indicates non-understanding, a language issue, or perhaps just some laziness when writing. For example, it should read "Let $J$ be the ideal **of** $Q[x]$...". Also, $J$ *is* a principal ideal; saying "the principal ideal of $J$ will be..." does not make sense. The above two comments point out the other two mistakes.

Comment: Why do you doubt it is correct?

Comment: True, I meant quotient @KentaS.

Comment: Thanks for the respons everyone :)